# The React way to retrieve (some) DOM values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

My react Menu component renders a list of links. Other parts need to animate (width and x/y pos) depending on the width of the Menu component's link's widths so all this needs to happen after all has rendered, and I need to read values from the DOM.

I'm looking for a proper way, no react anti-pattern, to handle this scenario but can't really sort it out in a way I'm happy with.

Here's an explanatory flow.

1) *User clicks a link in the menu.*

2) *Activate that link.*

```
this.setState({link: {active: true}});
```

3) *Look up and store what width the clicked element has.*

```
let w = this.myLink.offsetWidth; // myLink from refs.
```

4) *Update state with new width*

```
this.setState({styleState: { width: w }}); // Styles used in component elsewhere.
```

OK! This works fairly well, now I want to do the same for pos X/Y which makes things more complicated. Now I'll need to `getBoundingClientRect()` and take consideration to this element's parents to get the correct position etc.

I keep wishing for a sensible DOM API where I can grab values from the DOM (yep, jQuery style - like jqLite), then with values I update my state and thus re-render the component. I realize it wouldn't make sense to *manipulate* the DOM this way so I'm not trying to, but in this specific case the *truth* is actually in the DOM already and I need to extract it.

Is there a lib ppl use for these things, just to get a couple of getter methods like `el.width()`, `el.left()` for convenience?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its bad style to *read* size/styles of the dom after rendering. Just be sure to **not modify the dom directly**. The reason is that the real dom should always be in sync with the virtual dom.

I would encapsulate this behaviour in a custom Link component that receives an onClick:

```js
//untested pseudocode
class Link extends Component {

  handleRendered = (el) => {
    this.width = el.clientWidth;
    ....
  }

  handleClick = (ev) => {
    this.props.onClick({
      width: this.width,
      x: this.x,
      ...
    })
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div ref={(el) => this.handleRendered(el)} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );

  }
}


class MyPage extends Component {

  handleClick = ({width, ....}) => {
    this.setState({
      otherElementStyle: {
        width: width
      }
    })
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Link onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Menu1
      </Link>
    );

  }
}
```

Concerning your requested library, I'm not aware of any but I bet there is one.

Comment: This makes sense, two components feels cleaner. The problem with getting the left/top position of an element remains though. Strange if this is a rare case.

Comment: The problem with the positions is very similar. You just need to collect the positions of all involved components in the MyPage component and use them in the handleClick function. As the behaviour is related to multiple child components, this is the correct place to implement this. The child components should not know anything about the context in which they are used.

Comment: This is the reason I do not want to implement my own DOM solutions (`el.left()`). With vanilla javascript, calculating the posX of an element relative to it's closest positioned parent, which is what I need for my CSS, is not trivial. There has to be a DOM getter lib out there that isn't as huge as jQuery.